# Best practices for RxJS inside non-trivial Angular components

Tags: angular, redux, rxjs, observable

Our team is in the process of migrating from AngularJS to Angular (4).

Inside our Angular components, we use the RxJS library to work on observables returned from the Http, ActivatedRoute, etc. services or subjects receiving values from inputs on the user interface. When some processing is required on the values produced by these observables, we map or combine them into new observables to produce "derived" observables. Nothing special here.

We end up with components in which almost all the public properties bound from the templates are observables.

However, this technique seems to have major drawbacks:

- It requires a very good knowledge and understanding of the RxJS library and many tasks that formerly seemed simple have become very complex, with a lot of time spent debugging/optimizing observables subscriptions.
- Our templates are now filled with async pipes and we regularly run into Angular bugs like this one: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10165.

To give you an example, here is an simple case (not the worst, by far): the template of a pagination component. Notice the large number of async pipes, some of which are nested inside a structural directive, itself asynchronous (which causes the bug I just mentionned).

```
<nav aria-label="Pagination" class="mt-5" *ngIf="($items | async)?.length">
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li class="page-item" [class.disabled]="(currentPage$ | async) === 1">
      <a class="page-link" [routerLink]="" [queryParams]="{ page: (currentPage$ | async) - 1 }" queryParamsHandling="merge">Previous</a>
    </li>
    <li *ngFor="let page of (pages$ | async)" class="page-item" [class.active]="page === (currentPage$ | async)">
      <a class="page-link app-page-number" [routerLink]="" [queryParams]="{ page: page }" queryParamsHandling="merge">{{ page }} <span class="sr-only" *ngIf="page === (currentPage$ | async)">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="page-item" [class.disabled]="(currentPage$ | async) === (lastPage$ | async)">
      <a class="page-link" [routerLink]="" [queryParams]="{ page: (currentPage$ | async) + 1 }" queryParamsHandling="merge">Next</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Changing the "derived" observables into simple (non-observable) properties, filled from a .subscribe() helps reduce code complexity, as well as the number of async pipes inside the template. But this doesn’t feel like a satisfying solution.

Besides, we encounter some new problems related to change detection with the OnPush strategy. Since we turned our observables into "normal" properties and removed the async pipes, Angular is not aware anymore that we are changing these properties and we often have to call ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges().

We have so far not been able to find clear best practices on how to deal with RxJS inside non-trivial components. Would you have any suggestions on how to get around these difficulties? Could Redux be the solution to (some) of our problems?

**Edit: It turned out that the aforementioned "bug" is actually a misuse of the RxJS library on our part. See my contribution to the ([GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10165)) for more details.**

Comment: I wish I could give this 100 up votes! My app has gone through 3-4 evolutions of thought on this topic and I'm still not happy. Oh... and Angular 5 is out now... so get on that upgrade ;)

Comment: Redux is great (or ngrx in my case) but I don't think it does much to address what you are asking about since you are still dealing with observables.

Comment: Some of your async pain could be relieved by storing the result of the observable in a variable like this: `<div *ngIf="($items | async) as items"></div>`. The docs: https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#storing-conditional-result-in-a-variable

Comment: With redux/ngrx you would have the same result: templates that are full of async pipe calls. There is nothing wrong with that. You can reduce the number of calls that work with the same observable value by wrapping the html elements related to that obs$ with a ng-container. Example: <ng-container *ngIf="page$ | async as page"> and using the template variable page to access the stream value. And trust me on this one: wherever you call subscribe manually, your code can be refactored to something more reactive

Comment: @Jota.Toledo With Redux, would it be possible to subscribe to the store, copy all the store values to component properties each time the store changes, and call detectChanges() only there ?

Comment: Yes, you can subscribe to the store, push the data into component properties, and call detectChanges. I did that for a while which lead me to want lifecycle events to be observable so I could tear down my subscriptions with takeUntil(onDestroy) so that I wouldn't have to track them all and unsubscribe in ngOnDestroy.

Comment: We wrote an entire app in RxJS and my suggestion is: dont go overboard. RxJS has a place, but it's not a good substitute for every situtation. Its a very powerful tool, and it makes some tasks trivially easy. If used incorrectly (all over the place) however, it will reduce code readability and make the app harder to maintain. Our new app tries to strike a balance between synchronous code, promises and Rx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Change detection**

The problem of `*ngIf="(obs | async)"` is one of change detection. The variable `obs` does not itself change when emitting, coupled with this being an expression in the template, makes it hard for change detection to detect.

A couple of principles are worth thinking of in this scenario:

- Observable variables are "pipes", i.e wrappers for values passing through them not the changing values themselves. The two are often equated, but that's akin to thinking that an an array and array elements are the same thing.
- RxJs is an 'external' (non-Angular) library. With these libraries, we need to be aware of whether changes to data handled by the library are visible to Angular change detection.

A fix for [#10165](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10165) is

```
<div style="background-color: green;" *ngIf="trigger">{{(val1 | async)}}</div>
<div style="background-color: green;" *ngIf="!trigger">{{(val2 | async)}}</div>

ngOnInit() {
  this.trigger = this.ifObservable.subscribe();
}
```

**Dealing with async data**

On the wider issue of 'observables everywhere', you are quite right but is this not a problem inherent in the async nature of web apps?

It would be interesting to contrast your old AngularJS code to the new Angular code. Is there an increase in complexity for the same set of feature implementation?

A principle I like to apply is to handle 'one-shot' observables such as `http.get` by subscribing to them, and keep 'multi-shot' observables connected via async pipes.

**OnPush**

This is essentially a way to dial-down the amount of automatic change detection going on, and hence speed up the app. Of course, that means you may have to be fire change detection manually more often - speed vs complexity trade-off.

**Redux**

While Redux stores generally expose state as observables (so you still need async pipe in the template), it does remove complexity around multiple points of updates to state, which may mean less observables are required (or at least the observables are abstracted away from the components).

The only Redux flavour I've looked at which doesn't involve de-asyncing data in the template is  [Mobex](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx), which essentially converts simple variables into objects with getters and setters, which contain the logic to watch for the async changes and unwrap them. But it has problems/caveats too with arrays.

**Simplifying the template**

One way you ***might*** simplify the template you've shown (I haven't tested this) is to wrap it in a child component and pass in the unwrapped values

```
<nav aria-label="Pagination" class="mt-5" *ngIf="items.length">
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li class="page-item" [class.disabled]="currentPage === 1">
      <a class="page-link" [routerLink]="" [queryParams]="{ page: currentPage - 1 }" queryParamsHandling="merge">Previous</a>
    </li>
    <li *ngFor="let page of pages" class="page-item" [class.active]="page === currentPage">
      <a class="page-link app-page-number" [routerLink]="" [queryParams]="{ page: page }" queryParamsHandling="merge">{{ page }} <span class="sr-only" *ngIf="page === currentPage">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="page-item" [class.disabled]="currentPage === lastPage">
      <a class="page-link" [routerLink]="" [queryParams]="{ page: currentPage + 1 }" queryParamsHandling="merge">Next</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>


export class PageComponent {

  @Input() currentPage = 0;
  @Input() pages = [];
  @Input() items = [];
```

and in the parent,

```
<page-component [pages]="pages$ | async" [items]="items$ | async" [currentPage]="currentPage$ | async" >
```

Esstentially, @Input hooks into change detection, even with onPush strategy.
Be careful to give child inputs default values.

Comment: On the subject of your proposed fix for #10165, it seems that the *ngIf will be turned on as soon as the subscription is created, without regard as to whether the HTTP has already completed or not.

Comment: That could well be true if there was an HTTP call in #10165 example, but there's not.

Comment: The point is to illustrate exposing observable values to change detection.

Comment: @bygrace shows another way via the template `($items | async) as items` where items is added to the component implicitly. But, for clarity I prefer explicitly adding it.

Comment: Almost all of our observables are either mapped or "switchMapped" from Http requests observables. Therefore, the fix is not functionally equivalent for us.

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to be, but surely you can see that adding a variable to use as the ngIf trigger and setting it inside a subscribe of your observable **will** work?

Comment: Yes, I can see that it will work. Though we now end up with a mix of two different patterns to manage asynchronous data (| async + subscribe()).

Comment: That's the thing, once you understand why it occurs you can pick a fix that suits your preferences. I'm thinking `($items | async) as items` is closest. Not my preference - as I said I prefer to subscribe to single emit observables.